# Ruby - TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Tags: ruby, json, hash

Trying to parse some JSON, byt why is `text` empty?

**Desired output:**

`text` should return `Hello world\n\nApple, Harbor\n\nBanana, Kitchen\n\nMango, Bedroom`

```
text = "Hello world"

json = '{"fruits": [{"name": "Apple", "location": "Harbor"}, {"name": "Banana", "location": "Kitchen"}, {"name": "Mango", "location": "Bedroom"}]}'
fruits = JSON.parse(json)

def format_fruits(fruits)
  fruits.each do |fruit|
    puts "\n\n#{ fruit[0]['name'] }, #{ fruit[0]['location'] }"
  end.to_sentence
end

text += format_fruits(fruits)
text
```

**Current output:**

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
        from (irb):5:in `+'
        from (irb):5
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/mark/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
        from /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mark/.rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/mark/.rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):006:0> text
=> "Hello world"
irb(main):007:0>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `to_sentence`. Can you explain that?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method to_sentence' for #<Hash:0x7f571f746e18>` are you using any gem?

Comment: `to_sentence` is `ActiveSupport` [method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence) available in Rails. Also, it's  callable on Array, not on Hash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is a result of calling [`Array#to_sentence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence) on a hash.

More specifically, `fruits` is a `Hash`, and calling `fruits.each { ... }` returns the original `fruits` `Hash` unchanged. Thus calling `fruits.to_sentence` causes the observed error.

Here's a fixed-up version with comments denoting the changes:

```
require 'json'

text = "Hello world"

json = '{"fruits": [{"name": "Apple", "location": "Harbor"}, {"name": "Banana", "location": "Kitchen"}, {"name": "Mango", "location": "Bedroom"}]}'
fruits = JSON.parse(json)['fruits'] # append ['fruits']

def format_fruits(fruits)
  fruits.map do |fruit| # change each -> map
    "\n\n#{ fruit['name'] }, #{ fruit['location'] }" # delete puts, [0]
  end.join # change to_sentence -> join
end

text += format_fruits(fruits)
puts text
```

Output:

```
Hello world

Apple, Harbor

Banana, Kitchen

Mango, Bedroom
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an accompanying explanation as to what the issue actually was.

Answer (score 4):

In-case your json always contains "fruits" key, you can achieve this quite easily. Here:

```
fruits = JSON.parse(json)
#=> {"fruits"=>[{"name"=>"Apple", "location"=>"Harbor"}, {"name"=>"Banana", "location"=>"Kitchen"}, {"name"=>"Mango", "location"=>"Bedroom"}]}

fruits["fruits"].each { |hash|
  puts "\n\n#{hash['name']}, #{hash['location']}"
}
```

Another way to do this without using `fruits` key:

```
fruits.values.first.each { |hash|
  puts "\n\n#{hash['name']}, #{hash['location']}"
}
```